# Наследование PHP

Tags: наследование, php, ооп

Есть 3 класса.
[ReadDB](http://pastebin.com/17NY25rw) - класс для считывания данных из бд.
[User Class](http://pastebin.com/XCbcff3i) - класс пользователя,который наследует абстрактный класс ReadDB.
[Admin Class](http://pastebin.com/xQT4wjZT) - класс администратора,который наследует класс пользователя.

Почему то,в функции в классе администратора,когда я выставляю область видимости класс пользователя users:: я вижу из доступных функций только функцию select из класса ReadDB,а функции класса users мне не доступны,хотя стоит область видимости protected.PS при public тоже самое.В чём ошибка?

Comment: это нормально, что в ReadDB namespace закоментирован ?

Comment: [всё работает](http://ideone.com/KMOMgM)

Comment: @eicto за наводку на сервис спасибо !)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, или вы пытаетесь вызывать нестатические методы без создания объекта? Только select у вас static, значит только его можно вызвать без создания объекта.

Comment: комментировал в поисках решения.Да,спасибо,понял что из за статика всё))